# find branch name during git rebase

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

### What?

Is there a way to find the name of the branch-being-rebased during an interactive rebase, that is better than parsing `.git/rebase-merge/head-name`?

### Details

Normally I use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to get the branch name.  But during a rebase the branch is in a detached head state and rev-parse returns `HEAD`.

So now I'm parsing the `.git/rebase-merge/head-name` file if it exists to pull out the branch name.  Is there a method (porcelain or otherwise) to get this data?

### Usage:

```
git checkout "the_branch_name_I_want"
git rebase -i "some_other_branch_sha_etc"
# mark commit for edit ...
git magic-command # I'd like to get back "the_branch_name_I_want"
git rebase --continue
```

### Why?

Why do I want to do this?

I store metadata about the branch and fetch it in my `commit-msg` hook to append to my commit message.  I want this to work when `reword`ing or `edit`ing my commit messages during interactive rebase.

### Code:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "not in a git repo!"
    exit 2
fi
if [ "$branch" = "HEAD" ]; then
    # check if we are in a rebase
    head_name_file="$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/rebase-merge/head-name"
    if [ -f "${head_name_file}" ]; then
        branch=$(cut -f3- -d/ $head_name_file)
    else
        # ignore DETACHED HEAD state.
        exit 1
    fi
fi
## do something with branch
```

Comment: If you're rebasing one branch on top of another, is there any reason for you to do this in an interactive context?

Comment: `git status` (non-`--porcelain`) will tell you that you're in the middle of a rebase, and show you the branch name if available.  It gets it from `rebase-merge/head-name` or `rebase-apply/head-name` or `BISECT_START` as appropriate.  The format of this `status` output is not documented as machine-parseable, but it's probably safer to read that than to grub around with the same files `git status` reads, since at least you have just one concentrated place instead of three.  (BTW you should use `git rev-parse --git-dir` rather than assuming `.git`.)

Comment: @torek that's odd that it's in the friendly output for git status but not available in the --porcelain.  Also ++ for `--git-dir` vs `--show-toplevel` + `/.git/'.  Thanks.

Comment: @makoto : I am interactively rebasing specifically to edit my commit messages on my (personal) feature branch before merging.

Comment: I see that `git branch --edit-description` doesn't work during detached head.

Comment: What about this method? Is this accomplishing the same thing, just shorter? 
https://gmurphey.github.io/2013/02/02/ignoring-git-hooks-when-rebasing.html#.XkK1AhNKjOQ

Comment: @J.Munson : no, that url is not showing the same thing, it is equivalent to the method (`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`) described under "details" that I was working to replace/extend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to find the name of the branch-being-rebased during an interactive rebase, that is better than parsing .git/rebase-merge/head-name?

Note that with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), "`git branch --list`" during an interrupted "`rebase -i`" now lets users distinguish the case where a detached `HEAD` is being rebased, and a normal branch is being rebased.

So you still need to parse, but the output of the command itself is now useful.

See [commit 1f537be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f537be3f21ce1289c5c3ed9ebf58f02938ad9f7) (03 Apr 2018) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
See [commit a236f90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a236f900d8f60e567fca0106038f4797341d97b2) (03 Apr 2018) by [Kaartic Sivaraam (`sivaraam`)](https://github.com/sivaraam).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4cbaa6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4cbaa6b47fbdcf68bd06d4a6ebf550153fb18636), 25 Apr 2018)</sup>

> ### `branch --list`: print useful info whilst interactive rebasing a detached HEAD

> When rebasing interactively (`rebase -i`), "`git branch --list`" prints a line indicating the current branch being rebased.
> This works well when the interactive rebase is initiated when a local branch is checked out.
>
> This doesn't play well when the rebase is initiated on a detached HEAD.
> When "`git branch --list`" tries to print information related
> to the interactive rebase in this case it tries to print the name
> of a branch using an uninitialized variable and thus tries to
> print a "`null pointer string`".
> As a consequence, it does not provide useful information while also inducing undefined behavior.
>
> So, print the point from which the rebase was started when interactive rebasing a detached HEAD.

[See the test](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f537be3f21ce1289c5c3ed9ebf58f02938ad9f7/t/t3200-branch.sh#L1261-L1270).

---

> For some things, the `git log` is a better reference than the documentation. (I wonder why they don’t set an environment variable for the `--exec` command to use.)

True, `git log` can indeed provide valuable insights, especially for understanding the evolution of features and bug fixes in Git. By examining commit messages and the detailed explanations often included, you can gain a more in-depth understanding of the context and reasoning behind changes, which might not be as apparent in official documentation. That can be particularly useful for advanced users or those developing tools that integrate closely with Git.

Suggesting an environment variable for the `--exec` command speaks to a broader need for making information readily available in various Git operations, such as during a rebase.
Currently, Git does not set a specific environment variable that exposes the current branch name during a rebase for use with the `--exec` command in interactive rebases.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. For some things the `git log` is a better reference than the documentation. (I wonder why they don’t set an environment variable for the `--exec` command to use.)

Answer (score 10):

Although `git branch --list` shows a branch name (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50124157/10418734) for the details), it is not useful during the scripting as you need to parse the output.

I use the following function to get a branch name (based on `head-name` file):

```sh
rebasing-branch() {
    for location in rebase-merge rebase-apply; do
        path=$(git rev-parse --git-path ${location})
        if test -d ${path}; then
            revision=$(<${path}/head-name)
            echo ${revision##refs/heads/}
            return 0
        fi
    done
}
```

It shows the branch name during either regular or interactive rebase.